# "puts" method in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been doing some development with rails 3 and I was wondering why calling the "puts" method doesn't output to standard out.

How do I get this back?

Comment: Good point, didn't know that lol :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `puts`, use `logger.info`:

```
logger.info @collection.inspect
```

Comment: true, but thats 7 more characters than I want to type :-)

Comment: Ok. In ApplicationController, define `def log(obj); logger.info(obj); end`. Now you can use `log @collection.inspect` in your controllers. I even managed to save you a character. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the standard ruby way by calling `STDOUT << 'your output'`. Method `put` is not a rails speciality, it comes with ruby. If you use rails, you can also rely on the `logger` object.